# Write gif file take more time in android

Tags: android

I am using following code. To create gif file from multiple images from sdcard.

https://github.com/nbadal/android-gif-encoder/blob/master/GifEncoder.java

I used low resolution images .

Above class take more time to create gif file.

Please help me.

Comment: _"Above class take more time to create gif file."_ Takes more time _compared to what_?

Comment: Compare to other app available on market.

Comment: Well, that looks like an all-Java implementation. Try locating or writing a native implementation instead.

Answer (score 0):

on  emulator animation not work properly use Real device